# Javascript : Compile error while initialising array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to declare and init this array of objects called **graphdata**.

```
const graphdata = [
    {x:"Jan 01", y: 10 },
    {x:"Jan 02", y: 11 },
    {x:"Jan 03", y: 12 },
    {x:"Feb 01", y: 20 },
    {x:"Mar 01", y: 30 }
  ];
```

It gives me a compile error as `Parsing error: Unexpected token (Fatal)`

[image]

I tried both **const** and as well as **let** also.

*I assume they (const or let) do not make any difference for array of objects as the memory location is not mutated.*

Can someone let me what is wrong with this initialisation statement ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. Can you post more code, like what is before that statement ?

Comment: I think what wrong is the statement before.

Comment: May be a invisible character, try by deleting that line and retyping it

Comment: Are you trying to declare it inside a class and outside a function ? If so, the error is correct. You have to move the declaration outside the class. or inside a function as it suits you.